# how to get http text to textview android

Tags: android, web-services, http

im new to android development i want to get the source html text to a textview or to a string. i also add the permission internet manifest but still a cant get the text to textview. please help me.

my code is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    ////////////////////////
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try{
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://sinhaladic.com/" )).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        // Read the response
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer( );
        is = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
        String line = null;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            tv.append(new String(line + "\r\n"));
        }

        is.close();
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch ( Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { 
            is.close(); 
        } catch (Throwable t) {

        }
        try { 
            connection.disconnect(); 
        } catch (Throwable t) {

        };
    }
}//on create end
```

Comment: are you connection to network on the UI Thread?? where is your background Task?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform HttpRequests of any sort on the UI thread. For that you need to use a seperate thread. Try using **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** and write all your network operation codes in **doInBackground** function of asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about displaying some text from web into your android view, you can use webview instead of textview..

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>


webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://sinhaladic.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make http request in seperate thred or use AsyncTask(Android Way).
I am using it in thred it will hit url and return http text to you in form of string.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            InputStream is = null;
            String json;
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://sinhaladic.com/");
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();


    //json String is returnd Html text

                System.out.print("JSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"+json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error",
                        "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

        }
    }); t .start();
```